# Two maps into $[0,1]$ are equal at some point

Tags: gn.general-topology, fixed-point-theorems, continuum-theory

In the paper below, there appears the following theorem:
[image]
whose proof is left to the reader. It's not immediately obvious how I would prove this. How about the special case $X=Y=[0,1]$? It seems to be related to the fixed point property but I still don't see how to prove it.

*Lewis, Wayne*, [**Pseudo-arcs and connectedness in homeomorphism groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2043373), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 87, 745-748 (1983). [ZBL0525.54024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0525.54024).

Comment: For sure there is some regularity assumption here... which one? Otherwise it is hopeless.

Comment: We may guess that "map" means "continuous function".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the unit interval, the intermediate value theorem works. Consider the function $x \mapsto f(x) - g(x)$. Here, $f([0,1])$ is an interval $[a,b]$. Pick some $x_0 \in f^{-1}(a)$ and $x_1 \in f^{-1}(b)$. Since $g([0,1]) \subseteq [a,b]$, we find that $f(x_0) - g(x_0) \leq 0$, and $f(x_1) - g(x_1) \geq 0$. So, by the intermediate value theorem, there is some $x$ with $f(x) - g(x) = 0$.

In general, I reckon that the chainability of $Y$ replaces the linear order $\leq$ on $[0,1]$, and the connectedness of $X$ lets us essentially do the bisection argument for the intermediate value theorem in a way that makes the basic idea still work.

Comment: In particular, as suggested in @GeraldEdgar's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417483/two-maps-into-0-1-are-equal-at-some-point#comment1071492_417483), you are reading "map" to mean (as surely one must!) "continuous function".

Comment: Now to prove the theorem, if $Y$ is chainable then for every $n$ there is a mapping $f_n:Y\to [0,1]$ such that each point pre-image has diameter $<1/n$. You proved that there exists $x_n\in X$ such that $f_n\circ f(x_n)=f_n\circ g(x_n)$. Thus $f(x_n)$ and $g(x_n)$ are at most $1/n$ apart. By compactness of $X$ the sequence $(x_n)$ has an accumulation point $x\in X$. Then $f(x)=g(x)$.

By the way, I wonder if the theorem is still true if $X$ is complete and connected (but not necessarily compact)?

Comment: Here is a good reference with a proof: Nadler - Continuum theory: p. 253 - theorem 12.29. Using the fact that a subcontinuum of a chainable continuum is chainable (and chainable = arc-like), you get what you need.